# Loop: getPriceHtml() gives the same price for all products

Tags: magento, loops

there's a loop I'm using in a .phtml file, that looks like this:

```
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');    
$result = array();
$cnt = 0;
foreach ($result_skus as $index => $num) {
   $result[$cnt] = $index;
   $cnt ++;
}

for($cnt = 0; $cnt<count($result); $cnt++){
   //load product data
   $_product = $model->load($result[$cnt]);
   //display product name
   echo 'product name = '.$this->htmlEscape($_product->getName());
   echo '<br>';
   //display product price
   echo 'product price = '.$this->getPriceHtml($_product, true, '-bestseller')
}
```

**$_product->getName()** gives the correct product name
but 
**getPriceHtml()** gives the price of the first product that was accessed in the loop.

As a result, all products are displayed with the same price...

Is there something that I could do to refresh the product data? Why is price not changing for each product?

Comment: $model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is $this? `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List`? Why are you passing in the `idSuffix =  '-bestseller'`? I think you should just call `$this->getPriceHtml($_product, true);`

**EDIT

So now I am thinking two things:

a) following your comment above, I think you want to get a new model instance each time. So inside the loop either replace `$model` with `Mage::getModel('catalog/product');` or redeclare

`$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');`

at the start of the loop.

OR

b) following your comment below and taking a fresh look at this, I think you might need to get the price before generating the price HTML, so try adding the line:

$dummyPrice = $model->getPrice();

before `echo 'product price = '.$this->getPriceHtml($_product, true)`. And actually this might be the thing: because you are using the same instance $model and loading the new product on top of the old product I think $model is holding the first '$_product->getPrice()' price calculation and then not recalculating it because the function is:

```
public function getPrice()
{
    if ($this->_calculatePrice || !$this->getData('price')) {
        return $this->getPriceModel()->getPrice($this);
    } else {
        return $this->getData('price');
    }
}
```

If you don't do a) above, I think you need to force a price recalculation after each `$model->load();` so in that scenario your loop would be

```
   //load product data over the top of the previous loaded product
   $_product = $model->load($result[$cnt]);
   //force price recalculation
   $_product->getPriceModel()->getPrice($_product);
   //now ask for the price as HTML
   echo 'product price = '.$this->getPriceHtml($_product, true);
```

But I think it is better to use `Mage::getModel('catalog/product');` on each loop because we don't know what else Magento is or isn't clearing or overwriting.

This raises some interesting questions: Where are all the model instances going? Into memory? Maybe. I dug around a bit and found [an interesting article by Drew Gillson](http://www.drewgillson.com/blog/magento-collections-clearinstance/) about the function

`Mage_Core_Model_Abstract::clearInstance();`

So now I am learning things too and I think you want a loop like this:

```
for($cnt = 0; $cnt<count($result); $cnt++){
   //load product data
   $_product = $model->load($result[$cnt]);
   //display product name
   echo 'product name = '.$this->htmlEscape($_product->getName());
   echo '<br>';
   //display product price
   echo 'product price = '.$this->getPriceHtml($_product, true);
   //clear the $model for next time round (I reckon this will clear the calculated price too)
   $model->clearInstance();
}
```

---

After all that, if it still isn't working out I recommend some more debugging. If you are getting the correct product name then that is encouraging.

Inside your product loop also echo out:

```
$_product->getId();
$_product->getSku();
$_product->getData('price');
$_product->getPrice('');
$_product->getPriceModel()->getPrice($_product);
$_product->getPriceModel()->getBasePrice($_product);
$_product->getPriceModel()->getFinalPrice($_product);
$_product->getData('price');
$_product->getFormatedPrice('');
```

This should help confirm that you are loading the correct product info and expose what is available and hopefully shed some light on why you are not getting the price you expect. Many other price functions exist for tier prices and special prices and minimum prices.

If it still isn't doing what you want take a long look at your Magento settings and complete a re-index and cache-flush.

You could also pick an SKU that you know the price of and pass that through your code to see if it returns the expected price.

Comment: redeclaring '$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');' at the start of the loop was the one that did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `getPriceHtml()` function is defined in the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product` block, rather than the standard `Mage_Core_Block_Template`.

So you have to first instantiate the `Product block class which contains the method` in your custom script.

```
$product_block = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Product; 

$product_block->getPriceHtml($product,true);
```

so in your case just use this script

```
 $model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');    
    $result = array();
    $cnt = 0;
    foreach ($result_skus as $index => $num) {
       $result[$cnt] = $index;
       $cnt ++;
    }

    for($cnt = 0; $cnt<count($result); $cnt++){
       //load product data
       $_product = $model->load($result[$cnt]);
       //display product name
       echo 'product name = '.$this->htmlEscape($_product->getName());
       echo '<br>';

         $product_block = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Product;

 //instantiate the Product block class which contains the method

       //display product price
       echo 'product price = '. $product_block->getPriceHtml($_product,true);  

  }
```

Let me know if you have any problem